# Base class method alias

Tags: c++, using, overriding

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    void foo() //Here we have some method called foo.
    {
        std::cout << "Base::foo()\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() //Here we override the Base::foo() with Derived::foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::foo()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *base1 = new Base;
    Derived *der1 = new Derived;
    base1->foo(); //Prints "Base::foo()"
    der1->foo();  //Prints "Derived::foo()"
}
```

If I have the above stated classes, I can call the `foo` method from any of `Base` or `Derived` classes instances, depending on what `::foo()` I need. But there is some kind of problem: what if I need the `Derived` class instance, but I do need to call the `Base::foo()` method from this instance?

The solve of this problem may be next:
I paste the next method to the class Derived

```
public:
void fooBase()
{
    Base::foo();
}
```

and call `Derived::fooBase()` when I need `Base::foo()` method from Derived class instance.

The question is can I do this using `using` directive with something like this:

```
using Base::foo=fooBase; //I know this would not compile.
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
der1->Base::foo();  //Prints "Base::foo()"
```

You can call base class method using scope resolution to specify the function version and resolve the ambiguity which is useful when you don't want to use the default resolution.

Similar (Not exactly same case) example is mentioned @ [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup)

> ```
> struct B { virtual void foo(); };
> struct D : B { void foo() override; };
> int main()
> {
>     D x;
>     B& b = x;
>     b.foo(); // calls D::foo (virtual dispatch)
>     b.B::foo(); // calls B::foo (static dispatch)
> }
> ```